# Getting Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen) while trying to - File.open('condoleads1.json')

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to open a JSON file (using ruby on rails) that's on my computer titled "condoleads1.json". When I run the command - File.open('condoleads1.json'),I get the following error :Getting Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen)

Comment: Basic question, have you tried specifying the path to file with `File.open`?

Answer (score 0):

The file has to be in the directory where you run the program (formally, the working directory), not just anywhere on your computer. If you really do need to access a file that's somewhere else, use its full path (like `C:\Users\the\the.txt` or `/home/the/the.txt`) and not just the name

Comment: Thanks :) how can I add the files I am working with to the working directory?

Comment: I actually have no idea how ruby on rails works. But try to put the file at the root of your project.